# Laravel Livewire javascript code after model is load

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have one Laravel Livewire model open as bellow code

```php
public function confirmItemAdd() 
{
    $this->resetValidation();
    $this->confirmingItemAdd = true;
}
```

and my model window code in blade is

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="confirmingItemAdd">
```

I have one select2 in model and want to set value of `select2` on variable name `$s2v`
After search I findout that

```
$('.select2').val(s2v).trigger('change');
```

how can I set value of select2 on load on model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a browser event from the livewire component and listen for that event and change the select2 value accordingly (assuming the select2 part is wire:ignored).

```php
public $s2v = 'Test value';

public function confirmItemAdd() 
{
    $this->resetValidation();
    $this->confirmingItemAdd = true;
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('change-select2', $this->s2v);

}
```

in your layout file or with the stack in layout file you can listen for this event and trigger the change for the select2 as below,

```html
<script>
  $(window).on('change-select2', (e) => {
      $('.select2').val(e.detail).trigger('change');
   });
</script>
```

Note `e.detail` is the `$s2v` value passed from the livewire component.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much
only issue is it remove the custom validation error message... how can I set custom validation error message

Answer (score 1):

And what validation error is giving to you? you are reseting the validation error before the dispatchBrowserEvent...seem that even by JS you are changing the select2 value the property doesn't
EDITED

Ok, first a have a particular issue with select2 rendering after each refresh and find this solution. In the component a have this:

```
public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->emit('select2');
    }
```

and in blade parent or script section

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.initSelectCompanyDrop=()=>{
                $('#selectCompany').select2({
                    placeholder: '{{ __('locale.Select a Company') }}',
                    allowClear: true});
            }
            initSelectCompanyDrop();
            $('#selectCompany').on('change', function (e) {
                livewire.emit('selectedCompanyItem', e.target.value)
            });
            window.livewire.on('select2',()=>{
                initSelectCompanyDrop();
            });

        });

    </script>
```

If your issue with error bag persist, so you have to look into the kind of validation you're doing. In other case, I define global $message for a validation message but only works for $this->validate. Once I need redefine the validation, using Validator::make I have to create a new var $message for that inside the method

Comment: I am setting validation error message in Live-wire controller protected $messages = [
it work fine , only when select convert to select 2 validation error message become default with name of select. thanks

Comment: You have to hydrate the select2 for every refresh...I have similar issue and that was the solution

Comment: I have tried your method but its not working, I have defined my live-wire validation as bellow
protected $messages = [
    'pname => 'Please Choose Name',
    ];
and using
$this->validate();
it work fine and show custom validation if its normal select but as it become select 2 it give error but custom error as defined. Thanks